# Print first 25 lines of a text file, then next 25 etc

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to take a text file, and when the user presses any key 25 lines of a text file are printed, then when the key is pressed again, then next 25 lines are printed etc.

So far I've got this code:

```
f = open("lab6text.txt", "r");
print f

for line in f.readlines():
   print line,
```

But no matter what number I put in the:

```
f.readlines(25):
```

Every line is still printed. How can I fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: And why did you think `.readlines(25)` would read 25 lines? How about studying documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easier way to read files in "chunks" is to use the [`iter(callable, sentinel)`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#iter) function.

```
def make_lines_reader(fobj, number_of_lines):
    def reader():
        return ''.join(fobj.readline() for _ in range(number_of_lines))
    return reader

with open('the-file.txt') as f:
    for chunk in iter(make_lines_reader(f, 25), ''):
        print(chunk, end='')
        input()    #assuming python3, in python2 use raw_input()
```

This will print 25 lines from `the-file.txt` then wait for the user to press enter. Afterwards it will print other 25 lines etc.

Answer (score 1):

[`readlines`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.IOBase.readlines) does not take the number of lines as an argument. It instead takes a *hint*, which is the maximum number of bytes/characters to read in. Unless you know the length of each line, this probably won't serve your purposes well.

If you want to print the next 25 lines of a file, you could use a list comprehension, `readline`, and `join`:

```
print "".join([ f.readline() for _ in range(25) ])
```

In this manner, you wouldn't have to load all the file at once, but just the next 25 lines.

You could nest this (or something similar) inside a `while` loop to load more lines from the file when the user presses a key.

Answer (score 0):

You could declare a function that prints a maximum of 25 lines and return whether the end of the file were encountered.

```
def print25lines(f):
    for _ in range(25):
        line = f.readline()
        if line:
            print line,
        else:
            return False
    return True

with open('lab6text.txt', 'r') as f:
    while print25lines(f):
        # Wait user to press enter
        raw_input("Press Enter to continue...")
```